# Schedule a function to run at a future time with Cordova on Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, localnotification

I have an ionic app and I'd like to schedule a notification at a later time, and also calling some other function at a later time as well.

What I have now:

```
    var now = new Date();
    var _10SecondsFromNow = new Date(now.getTime() + (10 * 1000));
    $cordovaLocalNotification.schedule({
      id: 1,
      title: 'Title here',
      text: 'Text here',
      at: _10SecondsFromNow
    }, function(){
      console.log('callback') // never called
    })
    .then(function(){
      console.log('then'); // called right away
    });
```

The `.then` promise runs right away instead of when the notification occurs 10 seconds later. I also noticed in the [docs](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/04.-Scheduling#schedule-repeatedly) that there is a callback you can pass to `localNotification`, however, it is never called.

I am open to any way to schedule a future task, I am not limited to `localNotification` from cordova.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using `localNotifications` if you monitor either the `trigger` or `click` event, depending on what you want to achieve.

The `trigger` event will be fired once the notification is shown, which seems to be what you want and looks like this:

```
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaLocalNotification:trigger', function(event, notification, state) {
  // Your function here
})
```

Or you can use the `click` event, which is only fired once the user taps on the notification and opens your app, which looks like this:

```
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaLocalNotification:click', function(event, notification, state) {
  // Your function here
})
```

Both of these events are documented [here](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/localNotification/), but the official Cordova plugin documentation may also be of use, you can find it [here](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/09.-Events).